# Accessing elements of multiple layouts in single Activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-dialog

I have MainActivity in which `button` pops up dialogue box i.e. a new layout(custom layout). I want `TextView` in dialogue box to show data received from a String in mainactivity.

In short I want to access `TextView` of a custom layout in MainActivity.java. `setContent` remains on activity_main only and `fragments` can't help.

Comment: show how you create and show the dialog

Comment: for this, you need to display dialogue view with the help of inflater, which can help you find the text from textView and use that in the activity class.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood right, but:
- if you want to apply a custom layout to your dialog and access it's textView:

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);  
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);
TextView textView = dialog.findViewById(R.id.your_textView);
textView.setText(yourString);
dialog.show();
```

Will do the trick.

If you want to apply a string to a native Alert Dialog:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
View dialogView = inflater.inflate(your_layout, null);
new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setTitle("A string for the title")
    .setMessage("A string for the message")
    .setPositiveButton("A string for the positive button"), (dialog, which) -> {
                    dialog.dismiss();

                })
    .setNegativeButton("A string for the negative button"), (dialog, which) -> dialog.dismiss())
    .setView(dialogView)
    .show();
```

You can instantiate an AlertDialog this way, no need to create a variable.

If what you need isn't none of the above, let me know by explaining a little better. I will try to help

Comment: It worked Bro thanks but I was using AlertDialog earlier with my custom view. In Dialog, size of pop is not as expected it is smaller but in AlertDialog it was perfect as my layout, can you help me with this.

Comment: Can't I access all layouts other then setContent() one in any activity?